# How to change display output on template form?

Tags: python

I am working on gnuhealth opensource system, developed with python. I have no pre-knowledge on python.

I want to display/print client first & surname name, which appeared to be a `PARTY` on the code editor.

This code on the template only displayed/print client first name:

```
**
```

This is the corresponding codes on the editor.

```
invoice_address = fields.Many2One('party.address', 'Invoice Address',
                                  required=True, states=_STATES, depends=['state', 'party'],
                                  domain=[('party', '=', Eval('party'))])
```

Here is the code for the `PARTY` (first & surname) from the editor, which I want to replace with the above information.

```
party = fields.Many2One('party.party', 'Party',
        required=True, states=_STATES, depends=_DEPENDS)
```